# Graph API - How do I determined linked contacts?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

In Office 365 Contacts UI you can have contacts that are linked. When retrieving the contacts through the Graph API endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts` there is no field that indicates that the contacts are linked.

Contacts can be linked when they are created with the same email or you can specify any two contacts to link. So it is important to know when contacts are linked as they share data.

Using `https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/contacts` I have the PersonId field which allows me to determine a link.

How do I determine if a contact is linked and who it is linked to in the Graph API?

Comment: Linked contacts cross accounts (i.e. I can link my Thomas Nixon O365 contact with my Thomas Nixon Outlook.com contact). Those links are stored by/at the UI level.

Comment: Sorry, not cross account, I will give an example. 

In Office 365 Outlook People I have created two contacts in the Your Contacts folder.
1. tnixon@outlook.com
2. tnixon@hotmail.com
I then link these two contacts. I can now see only one contact and view the both emails in that contact.
If I pull the contacts through the API it shows that I have two contacts. I cannot tell that the data between the two contacts is linked, so I have to import two contacts into my system. If I knew they were linked then I would only import one with the combined data.

Comment: I understand but it doesn't change how links are stored. Linking isn't _limited_ to a single account and there aren't any properties on the contact object for storing linking metadata.